# Nested Sorting of React Table V7

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-table-v7

I am using [React Table V7](https://github.com/TanStack/table/blob/v7/docs/src/pages/docs/api/useSortBy.md).
I want the table to be always sorted by a specific column (Col A). Then if I click on any other column (Col B), it will sort table by column B with 2nd priority (with col A as first priority)
Anyone knows how to do it?

I found sortedIndex of column which represents like:

`sortedIndex = -1` means table is not sorted by this column
`sortedIndex = 0` means table is sorted by this col with highest priority (0)
`sorted Index = 1` means table is sorted by this col with second highest priority (1) and so on
But I can't set sortedIndex of any column and make it persist. When I click on other column it destroys previously set sortedIndex values.
In angular JS (UI Data Grid): this is done by adding `grouping: { groupPriority: 1 }, sort: { priority: 1, direction: 'asc' }` in the column definitions.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.